# template specialization for char[]

Tags: c++

```
template<class T>
T add(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return (a + b);
}

template<>
char add(const char& a, const char& b) {
    return a;
}

int main(){
    cout << add(1, 2) << "\n" 
        << add(1.0, 3.) << "\n"
        //error line
        << add("hello,", "world! ") << "\n" 
        << add('a', '1') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a template add function but specialize in type char. But it says that no instance of function template "add" matches the argument list.

[Error][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjrNC.png

Comment: The error happened on line "add("hello, ", "world! ")".

Comment: The problem isn't you specialization but the `add("hello,", "world! ")`. There you are trying to concatenate different-sized char-arrays by using the +-operator.

Comment: `const char& a` is a single character. You say `char []`, but you arent specializing for arrays

Comment: If I have to use this line, what should I do with the specialization?

Comment: Please _show the error_. The error is supposed to be informative. A written description of an error is less informative. Don't hide the information your compiler gave you and make people guess what it was. Just paste it. It's even less work for you than writing a description!

Comment: When asking questions involving build errors then please include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the build output and the errors you get. Also please add comments on the lines in the shown code where you get the errors. Please [edit] your question to improve it. Also please take some time to take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: On a note related to your problem: Literal strings are really *constant* arrays of characters, i.e. `const char[]` (or `const char*` as they decay to).

Comment: You need to add a specialization that takes two arrays and create some way to add those arrays together and return it.  Not sure exactly how you are going to accomplish that with this though.

Comment: You could add an overload for the `const char[]` version: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/KEneW1YT1) but I'm not exactly sure what you want.